# How can i make the window transparent in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, winui

I am developing a WinUI3 app and I want to make the window transparent. However, that doesn't seem to be easily possible anymore. In WPF i could just set AllowTransparency ="true" in my xaml window. How can i do that same with WinUI3? I want my window content to still be fully visible, but these black window edges gone.[image: window black background]

Setting the opacity of the full window seems to be possible, but i want only the window background to be transparent. Info about that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/614452/need-help-to-make-window-as-overlay-in-winui3-appl), however this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Have you seen that (most of it is Windows 11 only) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1247) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Summarize the solution in the link provided by Andrew:

You could try to use a SwapChainPanel as root to make a layered window transparency. And here is a sample you could refer to: https://github.com/castorix/WinUI3_SwapChainPanel_Layered

In win11, you just need to set the default corner, it will work and remove the border + shadow. You could try to use `DWMWCP_DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WinUIEx, which I assume - you can use `Window.SystemBackdrop`. Example can be seen [here](https://dotmorten.github.io/WinUIEx/concepts/CustomBackdrops.html#transparent-backdrop), if it's not available for you make sure you've updated WinUIEx.